# Java count to the number

Tags: java, count

I am new in JAVA i do not know how to make a count program, for example I will write a number ex. `16` and the program to count to the 16 but to go like `1, 3, 5, 7, 9`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner java = new Scanner(System.in);
    int from;
    int to;
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    to = (int) java.nextDouble();
    for (from = 1; from < to; from++) {
        System.out.println(to);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Come back when you have actually tried something, and have a specific question we can help you with.

Comment: Whoah, buddy! Take a step back and print out `Hello, world!` before you go doing fancy things.

Comment: `Scanner java = new Scanner(System.in);
        int OD;
        int DO;
        System.out.println("Vnesi broj: ");
        DO = (int) java.nextDouble();
        for (OD = 1; OD < DO; OD++) {
            System.out.println(DO);
        }`

Comment: You're able to edit your question to post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner java = new Scanner(System.in);
int from, to;
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
to = java.nextInt();
for (from = 1; from < to; from+=2) {
    System.out.println(from);
}
```

I took your code, and here is what I changed:

- `java.nextInt()` instead of using `java.nextDouble()` and casting it to `int`
- `from+=2` instead of `from++`, because you want to count two by two, and not one by one
- `System.out.println(from);` instead of `System.out.println(to);`, because you want to print the number you are increasing, not the number you want to reach.

Comment: Why here at this line `for (OD = 1; OD < DO; OD+=2) {` its not possible to make like this `for (OD = 1; OD < DO; OD+2) {` ? its more simple ...

Comment: @user3390702 You can write it `OD=OD+2` if you want, but not just `OD+2`, because you want to store the result in the variable, and `OD+2` will not store it, just calculate it.

Comment: Thank you all for the help i just needed this program for making sure that it is possible to be programmed, and what is your suggestion from where to start learning ? EDIT: and give me suggestions what other programs to make ? :)

Comment: @user3390702 I think you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info there are some links to beginners' resources (and more advanced ones). One of the usual advanced-but-not-too-much program you can write is a tic-tac-toe game (but that's just my suggestion, you can certainly find a lot of good ideas in the tutorials).

Comment: What is the best programming language in the world ?

Comment: @user3390702 It's still to be invented :-).

Comment: So i'm good with java or to start C++ ? Because i searched something now on the internet and i saw that with C++ you can do games and with java don't and most of the games been made with C++

Comment: Java or C++ are both good, and you can also create games in Java (all the games on android are made in Java, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Look out for 'for loops' they are great counters used in Java. Look up tutorials.

Look out for 'for loops' they are great counters used in Java. Look up tutorials.

```
Scanner java = new Scanner(System.in);

int OD;
int DO;

System.out.println("Vnesi broj: ");
DO = (int) java.nextDouble();

for (OD = 1; OD < DO; OD++) { 
    System.out.println(DO);
}
```

You have the value in the 'System.out.println(DO);` wrong. change it to the one that the for loop counts with.

With that your saying DO = 1, if OD is less than DO, OD equals OD plus 1. print out OD

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [structure of a `for-loop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html),

```
for (initialization; termination;
     increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

*Taken from The `for` Statement trail*

This means you control the value to start at, the termination clause (how the loop is terminated) and how a value might be incremented on each loop, for example...

```
for (int count = 0; count < 16; count += 2) {...
```